# How to pass arguments to ruby script

Tags: ruby, wordpress, export, jekyll

I'm trying to import posts from a WordPress to jekyll

https://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpressdotcom/

I should run:

```
$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({
  "source" => "wordpress.xml",
  "no_fetch_images" => false,
  "assets_folder" => "assets"
})'
```

But I need to modify the script first
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import/blob/v0.14.0/lib/jekyll-import/importers/wordpressdotcom.rb.

How can I run downloaded script wordpressdotcom.rb passing arguments like `source` and `assets_folder`?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the old `jekyll-import` v1.x method. The new method of importing is running `jekyll import` from the command line.

Simply run:

```
gem install jekyll-import
```

Then:

```
jekyll import wordpressdotcom --help
```

Output:

```
Usage:

  jekyll import wordpressdotcom [options]

Options:
            --source FILE  WordPress export XML file (default: "wordpress.xml")
            --no-fetch-images  Do not fetch the images referenced in the posts
            --assets_folder FOLDER  Folder where assets such as images will be do
```

As you can see, you can specify `source` and `assets_folder` on the command line.

**If you want to modify the source and run the gem yourself**:

First:

```
git clone https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-import
bundle install
```

Now edit the code as you please, then:

```
rake console
```

And you will get an `irb` console where you can run

```
JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run(...)
```

If you want to install your modified gem into the system instead:

```
rake install
```

Comment: OK, but I need to modify downloaded script before importing.

Comment: See my edit. You can specify those options on the command line.

Comment: except passing options I need to modify script to save permalink for every post in post properties

Comment: The fact that you're hacking this gem doesn't change the way it is invoked in the command line.

Comment: @perffaith See my last edit. You can download the code yourself, modify it as you wish, and then run it they way you want in your irb console.